# How to create and preserve relationships of imported data in MS Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm building an MS Access application that will do a one-time import of data from CSV files.  So far, so good; I can use the import wizards to do that.  After the tables (Manufacturer, Purchased From, and Sold To) are imported, I need to import a 4th table that will refer to data in the other three (as well as some other data like price, commission, etc).

My problem is that when I import the data into the 4th table, the fields will contain text, not the keys for the Manufacturer, Purchased From, and Sold To tables.  How can you establish the relationships when doing an import?  Is there a simple method to import data in this fashion, or is VBA needed?

Comment: That's simple : Do not establish any relationships before ALL your tables are imported. FIrst import everything. Ensure that all the keys/foreign keys in all tables have the same data type, if not convert. And only after all this is done, activate the relationships / referential integrity

Comment: Is the data for the four tables contained in the one CSV file?  I usually build my empty tables first with all the relationships built.  I then have a temporary table to import the raw data into.  I then use append queries to normalise the data - place all the manufacturers in one table, all customers in another, etc.  I finally build my main data table cross-referencing the data in each table with the raw data to return the foreign key that needs adding to my final table.

Comment: I'm running a simple test first, and I have four tables:  Make, Purchased From, Sold To, and Transactions.  They are (in this test) all coming from one Excel workbook.  I import the sheets into the respective tables, and then tried establishing relationships between them (maintaining referential integrity).  When I try to map the Make:Make column with the Transactions:Make column, Access gives me an error:  "No unique index found for the referenced field on the primary table" --same thing for the others.  I'll try Darren's suggestion next.

Answer (score 0):

To establish relationship between "make.make" and "transactions.make", first you have to declare "make.make" as primary key for table "make".